# Can we rewrite the formula for the tangent line?

Tags: limits

I just started calculus and was taught the formula to find the tangent line of a function using limits is a such.
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
The formula above seems to be approaching the point from the positive direction. However wouldn't the formula below be equally as valid since it is the same but instead approaches from the negative direction?
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(x-h)}{h}$$
When I compute the tangent line using the second formula it seems to yield a incorrect answer .

Comment: Tangent at a point is defined if $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0^{-}}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(x-h)-f(x)}{h}$$.

Comment: Since $h\to0$ is the same as $-h\to0$, both formulas are equivalent (just replace $h$ by $-h$).

Comment: @ProfessorVector If i just swap the sign of h that will simply be the same as the first formula. The way I wrote it is such that I want to use the point before f(x) to calculate the slope rather than the point after f(x) to calculate the slope.

Comment: It is always the first formula, it's the definition. Your problem (and not only _your_ problem) is that you think $h$ has to be positive. The definition of a derivative doesn't say so: it's $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
not $$\lim_{h\to 0+}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

Comment: "When I compute the tangent line using the second formula it seems to yield a incorrect answer." Can you tell us in more detail what you did?

Comment: Numbers are positive *and* negative.

Comment: I believe that when you tried your example, you must have made an error.  Will you please add your attempt to your question?

Comment: @coderhk I feel I have been remiss unless I point out that the definition we have been discussing is not the definition of the formula for the tangent line, but the definition of the slope of the tangent line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you could.

$$f'(a) = \lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} = \lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(a)-f(x)}{a-x} $$

Now replace $x$ by $a-h$ to get 
$$f'(a) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(a)-f(a-h)}{a-(a-h)} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(a)-f(a-h)}{h} $$

Change the $a$ to $x$ for your suggestion.

OR
In
$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

Let $t = x+h$, so $x = t-h$.  If the above limit exists, then the limit below exists and is the same.

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(t)-f(t-h)}{h}$$.